# Store MySQLi Query in a PHP Variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to pass a MySQL query into a variable but it is not storing it correctly. I am wanting the query result to be stored as a string.

Here is my attempt:

```
$authorid = $db->query("SELECT Author_ID FROM Authors WHERE Author_Name = '$author'");
```

The query works correctly in PHPMyAdmin so I know it is returning the correct information but I am unsure if this is the correct way to store it.

I am trying to use it for this:

```
$authoredquery = $db->query("SELECT Author_ID, Article_ID 
FROM Articles_Authored 
WHERE Author_ID = '$authorid' AND Article_ID ='$articleid'");
```

All of the query is spelled correctly. I was under the impression that this stored the query result as a string....

Here is a portion of the php code that runs after a form is submitted:

```
    $dbHost = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "admin";
    $dbPassword = "qegc0Qfs";
    $dbName = "webdb";

    // Create connection
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
    // Check connection
    if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
    } else {
    // Post PHP variables
    $journal = $_POST['journal_radio'];
    $article_name = $_POST['article_name'];
    $author1 = $_POST['author1_name'];
    $author1uni = $_POST['author1_university'];
    $author2 = $_POST['author2_name'];
    $author2uni = $_POST['author2_university'];
    $author3 = $_POST['author3_name'];
    $author3uni = $_POST['author3_university'];
    $author4 = $_POST['author4_name'];
    $author4uni = $_POST['author4_university'];
    $author5 = $_POST['author5_name'];
    $author5uni = $_POST['author5_university'];
    $author6 = $_POST['author6_name'];
    $author6uni = $_POST['author6_university'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $security = $_POST['is_security'];
    function authorinfoinsert($author, $number, $authoruni, $articleid, $article, $db){
            //check if Author already exists
            $authorquery = $db->query("SELECT Author_Name FROM Authors WHERE Author_Name = '$author'");
            if($authorquery->num_rows != 0) {
               echo '<a href="> New Input </a><br />';
               echo 'Author ' . $number . ' - ' . $author . ' - already present<br />';

            } else {
                //insert author if doesnt exist
                $authorinsert = "INSERT INTO Authors (Author_Name) VALUES ('$author')";

                if ($db->query($authorinsert) === TRUE) {
                echo 'Author ' . $number . ' - ' . $author . ' - created successfully.<br />';
                } else {
                echo 'Error: ' . $authorinsert . '<br />' . $db->error . '<br />';
                }
              }

            // store Author Author_ID value

            $authorid = $db->query("SELECT Author_ID FROM Authors WHERE Author_Name = '$author'");


            //check if Author University exists
            $authoruniquery = $db->query("SELECT University_Name FROM University WHERE University_Name = '$authoruni'");

            if($authoruniquery->num_rows != 0) {
               echo '<a href=""> New Input </a><br />';
               echo 'Author ' . $number . ' University already present <br />';

            } else {
                //insert university if doesnt exist
                $uniinsert = "INSERT INTO University (University_Name) VALUES ('$authoruni')";

                if ($db->query($uniinsert) === TRUE) {
                echo 'Author ' . $number . ' University - ' . $authoruni . ' - created successfully.<br />';
                } else {
                echo 'Error: ' . $uniinsert . "<br>" . $db->error . '<br />';
                }
              }

            // store Author University_ID value
            $authoruniid = $db->query("SELECT University_ID FROM University WHERE University_Name = '$authoruni'");
            echo $authoruniid;
            //Enter Author and Article in Articles_Authored
            $authoredquery = $db->query("SELECT Author_ID, Article_ID FROM Articles_Authored WHERE Author_ID = '$authorid' AND Article_ID ='$articleid'");
            if($authoredquery->num_rows != 0) {
               echo '<a href=""> New Input </a><br />';
               echo 'Article Authored entry for Author ' . $number . ' - ' . $author . ' - already present<br />';

            } else {
            $articlesauthoredinsert = "INSERT INTO Articles_Authored (Article_ID, Author_ID, Name_Authored_As) VALUES ('$articleid','$authorid','$author')";

                if ($db->query($articlesauthoredinsert) === TRUE) {
                echo 'Article Authored - Author ' . $number . ' - created successfully <br />';
                } else {
                echo 'Error: ' . $articlesauthoredinsert . "<br>" . $db->error . '<br />';
                }
            }

            //Enter Author University instance in Author_University
            $authoruniinsert = "INSERT INTO Author_University (Article_ID, Author_ID, University_ID) VALUES ('$articleid','$authorid','$authoruniid')";

                if ($db->query($authoruniinsert) === TRUE) {
                echo 'University instance for Author ' . $number  . ' created successfully<br />';
                } else {
                echo 'Error: ' . $authoruniinsert . "<br>" . $db->error . '<br />';
                }
            }
```

And I pass the args to the function like this:

```
authorinfoinsert($author1, 1, $author1uni, $articleid, $article, $db);
```

Here is all of the code if that helps. Sorry I know its a  lot:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Input Form - Research Ranker</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#article_name" ).autocomplete({
   </head>
      
<body>



<?PHP
 
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    print '
 <div class="container-fluid ui-widget">


 <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="test.php" onsubmit="return confirm("Is all of your data correct?");">
 <fieldset>

 <!-- Article Input -->
 <legend>Article Input</legend>

 <!-- Journal Radio Buttons (value is journal ISSN)-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="journal_radio">Journal</label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-0">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-0" value="2162-9730" checked="checked">
    MIS Quarterly
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-1">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-1" value="1047-7047">
    Information Systems Research
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-2">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-2" value="0742-1222">
    Journal of Management Information Systems
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-3">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-3" value="1536-9323">
    Journal of the Association for Information Systems
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-4">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-4" value="1476-9344">
    European Journal of Information Systems
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-5">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-5" value="1365-2575">
    Information Systems Journal
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-6">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-6" value="0963-8687">
    Journal of Strategic Information Systems
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-7">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-7" value="0268-3962">
    Journal of Information Technology
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-8">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-8" value="0167-9236">
    Decision Support Systems
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-9">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-9" value="0378-7206">
    Information and Management
  </label>
   </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Article Name Input-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="article_name">Article Name:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-5">
   <input id="article_name" name="article_name" type="text" placeholder="Article Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 1-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author1_name">Author 1:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author1_name" name="author1_name" type="text" placeholder="Author Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 1 University -->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author1_university">University:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author1_university" name="author1_university" type="text" placeholder="Author University" class="form-control input-md" required="">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 2-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author2_name">Author 2:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author2_name" name="author2_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 2 University-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author2_university">University:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author2_university" name="author2_university" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 3-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author3_name">Author 3:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author3_name" name="author3_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 3 University-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author3_university">University:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author3_university" name="author3_university" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 4-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author4_name">Author 4: </label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author4_name" name="author4_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 4 University-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author4_university">University:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author4_university" name="author4_university" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 5-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author5_name">Author 5:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author5_name" name="author5_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 5 University-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author5_university">University:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author5_university" name="author5_university" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 6-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author6_name">Author 6:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author6_name" name="author6_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 6 University-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author6_university">University:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author6_university" name="author6_university" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Select Year Published -->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="year">Year Published</label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
  <select id="year" name="year" class="form-control">
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
  </select>
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Is Security Checkbox -->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="is_security"></label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
  <label class="checkbox-inline" for="is_security-0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="is_security" id="is_security" value="1">
    Security Related
  </label>
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Submit Form Button -->
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-4 control-label">
  <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
   </div>
 </div>

 </fieldset>
 </form>


 </div>';
 
 } else {
  
  $dbHost = "localhost";
  $dbUsername = "admin";
  $dbPassword = "qegc0Qfs";
  $dbName = "webdb";

  // Create connection
  $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
  // Check connection
  if ($db->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
  } else {
  // Post PHP variables
  $journal = $_POST['journal_radio'];
  $article_name = $_POST['article_name'];
  $author1 = $_POST['author1_name'];
  $author1uni = $_POST['author1_university'];
  $author2 = $_POST['author2_name'];
  $author2uni = $_POST['author2_university'];
  $author3 = $_POST['author3_name'];
  $author3uni = $_POST['author3_university'];
  $author4 = $_POST['author4_name'];
  $author4uni = $_POST['author4_university'];
  $author5 = $_POST['author5_name'];
  $author5uni = $_POST['author5_university'];
  $author6 = $_POST['author6_name'];
  $author6uni = $_POST['author6_university'];
  $year = $_POST['year'];
  $security = $_POST['is_security'];
  function authorinfoinsert($author, $number, $authoruni, $articleid, $article, $db){
    //check if Author already exists
    $authorquery = $db->query("SELECT Author_Name FROM Authors WHERE Author_Name = '$author'");
    if($authorquery->num_rows != 0) {
       echo '<a href=""> New Input </a><br />';
       echo 'Author ' . $number . ' - ' . $author . ' - already present<br />';
   
    } else {
     //insert author if doesnt exist
     $authorinsert = "INSERT INTO Authors (Author_Name) VALUES ('$author')";
    
     if ($db->query($authorinsert) === TRUE) {
     echo 'Author ' . $number . ' - ' . $author . ' - created successfully.<br />';
     } else {
     echo 'Error: ' . $authorinsert . '<br />' . $db->error . '<br />';
     }
      }
      
    // store Author Author_ID value
    
    $authorid = $db->query("SELECT Author_ID FROM Authors WHERE Author_Name = '$author'");
    
    
    //check if Author University exists
    $authoruniquery = $db->query("SELECT University_Name FROM University WHERE University_Name = '$authoruni'");
    
    if($authoruniquery->num_rows != 0) {
       echo '<a href=""> New Input </a><br />';
       echo 'Author ' . $number . ' University already present <br />';
   
    } else {
     //insert university if doesnt exist
     $uniinsert = "INSERT INTO University (University_Name) VALUES ('$authoruni')";
    
     if ($db->query($uniinsert) === TRUE) {
     echo 'Author ' . $number . ' University - ' . $authoruni . ' - created successfully.<br />';
     } else {
     echo 'Error: ' . $uniinsert . "<br>" . $db->error . '<br />';
     }
      }
    
    // store Author University_ID value
    $authoruniid = $db->query("SELECT University_ID FROM University WHERE University_Name = '$authoruni'");
    echo $authoruniid;
    //Enter Author and Article in Articles_Authored
    $authoredquery = $db->query("SELECT Author_ID, Article_ID FROM Articles_Authored WHERE Author_ID = '$authorid' AND Article_ID ='$articleid'");
    if($authoredquery->num_rows != 0) {
       echo '<a href=""> New Input </a><br />';
       echo 'Article Authored entry for Author ' . $number . ' - ' . $author . ' - already present<br />';
   
    } else {
    $articlesauthoredinsert = "INSERT INTO Articles_Authored (Article_ID, Author_ID, Name_Authored_As) VALUES ('$articleid','$authorid','$author')";
    
     if ($db->query($articlesauthoredinsert) === TRUE) {
     echo 'Article Authored - Author ' . $number . ' - created successfully <br />';
     } else {
     echo 'Error: ' . $articlesauthoredinsert . "<br>" . $db->error . '<br />';
     }
    }
    
    //Enter Author University instance in Author_University
    $authoruniinsert = "INSERT INTO Author_University (Article_ID, Author_ID, University_ID) VALUES ('$articleid','$authorid','$authoruniid')";
    
     if ($db->query($authoruniinsert) === TRUE) {
     echo 'University instance for Author ' . $number  . ' created successfully<br />';
     } else {
     echo 'Error: ' . $authoruniinsert . "<br>" . $db->error . '<br />';
     }
    }

    
    
    //check if article exist
    $articlequery = $db->query("SELECT Article_Title, ISSN FROM Articles WHERE Article_Title = '$article_name' AND ISSN = '$journal'");
    if($articlequery->num_rows != 0) {
      echo '<a href=""> New Input </a><br />';
      echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Article Already Present');</script>";
  
    } else {

    //insert article if doesn't exist 
    $articleinsert = "INSERT INTO Articles (ISSN, Year_Published, Is_Security, Article_Title)
    VALUES ('$journal','$year','$security','$article_name')";

     if ($db->query($articleinsert) === TRUE) {
     echo 'New Article - ' . $article_name . ' - created successfully<br />';
     } else {
     echo 'Error: ' . $articleinsert . "<br>" . $db->error . '<br />';
     }
    // store Article_ID value
    $articleid = $db->query("SELECT Article_ID FROM Articles WHERE Article_Title = '$article_name' AND ISSN = '$journal'");
    
    //insert author 1 info
    authorinfoinsert($author1, 1, $author1uni, $articleid, $article, $db);
    //check if Author 2 has input
    if (isset($author2)){
     authorinfoinsert($author2, 2, $author2uni, $articleid, $article, $db);    
    }
    
    //check if Author 3 has input
    if (isset($author3)){
     authorinfoinsert($author3, 3, $author3uni, $articleid, $article, $db);   
    }
    //check if Author 4 has input
    if (isset($author4)){
     authorinfoinsert($author4, 4, $author4uni, $articleid, $article, $db);   
    }
    
    //check if Author 5 has input
    if (isset($author5)){
     authorinfoinsert($author5, 5, $author5uni, $articleid, $article, $db);   
    }

    //check if Author 6 has input
    if (isset($author6)){
     authorinfoinsert($author6, 6, $author6uni, $articleid, $article, $db);   
    } else{
     
     $db->close();
     
    }
   }
  }
 }
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is your error?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Theres no error its just not executing past $authoruniid 
I've tried to echo $authorid and $authoruniid and it stalls at the echo attempt

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I think its haulting when I try to use $authorid in the sql query $authoredquery

Comment: Which part of the code is not working.. Aur your expected flow and result?

Comment: @Minato it isnt executing the $authoredquery and i believe its because $authorid isnt passing to it correctly but am unsure how to fix it

Comment: @Minato I added rest of code

Comment: When you try and echo $authorid, does it work? Or does it break before that?

Comment: If I do it right after this line like this it stops there   
   `$authorid = $db->query("SELECT Author_ID FROM Authors WHERE Author_Name = '$author'");`  
    `echo $authorid;`

Comment: And does it show anything? Try var_dump($authorid);

Comment: @ChrisEvans instead of `echo $authorid;`?

Comment: @ChrisEvans it printed `object(mysqli_result)#5 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: @TaylorClark you need to call fetch on the result object to get the result..

Comment: @TaylorClark like `$authorid = $authorid->fetch_assoc()["authorid"];`

Comment: @TaylorClark read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) for more information.. you always need to call `fetch` on mysqli or mysql result object in php to get the query result as an associated array

Comment: @Minato its saything that `$authorid = $authorid->fetch_assoc()["authorid"];` gets an error of `syntax error, unexpected '['`

Comment: @TaylorClark it was just for reference purpose not literal .. you need to do it in 2 steps.. `$result = $db->query("your_query");` then `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();` then `$authorid = $row["Author_ID"];` then `$result->free();`

Comment: @Minato Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @TaylorClark dude and have a error handling mechanism as well.. see [Mysqli::fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) for further information

Comment: @TaylorClark dude did it work.. And No Problem... #SoReadyToHelp :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so from what you've told me, you're trying to use the object as a string, which is why it's not working.

$authorid is just $db->query(); which returns an object that you need to do something with. In this case, you need to grab the results from it like so:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT Author_ID FROM Authors WHERE Author_Name = '$author'");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$authorid = $row['Author_ID'];
```

Try that :)

Comment: Is this necessary on things such as this `$authorquery = $db->query("SELECT Author_Name FROM Authors WHERE Author_Name = '$author'");
    if($authorquery->num_rows != 0) {......`

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that it's returning an array rather than a string, which is why "echo" and "print" won't work.

You might try `print_r($authoruniid)` to see the structure of the array, then access your data through there.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use mysqli `fetch_assoc()` to getting result of query

you must change your code to:

```
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "admin";
$dbPassword = "qegc0Qfs";
$dbName = "webdb";

// Create connection
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
// Check connection
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
} else {
// Post PHP variables
    $journal = $_POST['journal_radio'];
    $article_name = $_POST['article_name'];
    $author1 = $_POST['author1_name'];
    $author1uni = $_POST['author1_university'];
    $author2 = $_POST['author2_name'];
    $author2uni = $_POST['author2_university'];
    $author3 = $_POST['author3_name'];
    $author3uni = $_POST['author3_university'];
    $author4 = $_POST['author4_name'];
    $author4uni = $_POST['author4_university'];
    $author5 = $_POST['author5_name'];
    $author5uni = $_POST['author5_university'];
    $author6 = $_POST['author6_name'];
    $author6uni = $_POST['author6_university'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $security = $_POST['is_security'];

    function authorinfoinsert($author, $number, $authoruni, $articleid, $article, $db) {
//check if Author already exists
        $authorquery = $db->query("SELECT Author_Name FROM Authors WHERE Author_Name = '$author'");
        if ($authorquery->num_rows != 0) {
            echo '<a href="myUrl"> New Input </a><br />';
            echo 'Author ' . $number . ' - ' . $author . ' - already present<br />';
        } else {
//insert author if doesnt exist
            $authorinsert = "INSERT INTO Authors (Author_Name) VALUES ('$author')";

            if ($db->query($authorinsert) === TRUE) {
                echo 'Author ' . $number . ' - ' . $author . ' - created successfully.<br />';
            } else {
                echo 'Error: ' . $authorinsert . '<br />' . $db->error . '<br />';
            }
        }

// store Author Author_ID value

        $authorid = $db->query("SELECT Author_ID FROM Authors WHERE Author_Name = '$author'");
        while ($row = $authorid->fetch_assoc()) {
            /
            echo $row['Author_ID'];
        }
//check if Author University exists
        $authoruniquery = $db->query("SELECT University_Name FROM University WHERE University_Name = '$authoruni'");

        if ($authoruniquery->num_rows != 0) {
            echo '<a href="myUrl"> New Input </a><br />';
            echo 'Author ' . $number . ' University already present <br />';
        } else {
//insert university if doesnt exist
            $uniinsert = "INSERT INTO University (University_Name) VALUES ('$authoruni')";

            if ($db->query($uniinsert) === TRUE) {
                echo 'Author ' . $number . ' University - ' . $authoruni . ' - created successfully.<br />';
            } else {
                echo 'Error: ' . $uniinsert . "<br>" . $db->error . '<br />';
            }
        }

// store Author University_ID value
        $authoruniid = $db->query("SELECT University_ID FROM University WHERE University_Name = '$authoruni'");
        while ($row = $authorid->fetch_assoc()) {/// better use this in a while loop to getting all records
            echo $row['University_ID'];
        }
//Enter Author and Article in Articles_Authored
        $authoredquery = $db->query("SELECT Author_ID, Article_ID FROM Articles_Authored WHERE Author_ID = '$authorid' AND Article_ID ='$articleid'");
        if ($authoredquery->num_rows != 0) {
            echo '<a href="myUrl"> New Input </a><br />';
            echo 'Article Authored entry for Author ' . $number . ' - ' . $author . ' - already present<br />';
        } else {
            $articlesauthoredinsert = "INSERT INTO Articles_Authored (Article_ID, Author_ID, Name_Authored_As) VALUES ('$articleid','$authorid','$author')";

            if ($db->query($articlesauthoredinsert) === TRUE) {
                echo 'Article Authored - Author ' . $number . ' - created successfully <br />';
            } else {
                echo 'Error: ' . $articlesauthoredinsert . "<br>" . $db->error . '<br />';
            }
        }

//Enter Author University instance in Author_University
        $authoruniinsert = "INSERT INTO Author_University (Article_ID, Author_ID, University_ID) VALUES ('$articleid','$authorid','$authoruniid')";

        if ($db->query($authoruniinsert) === TRUE) {
            echo 'University instance for Author ' . $number . ' created successfully<br />';
        } else {
            echo 'Error: ' . $authoruniinsert . "<br>" . $db->error . '<br />';
        }
    }
```

for more information about mysql_fetch_assoc() click [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)